# What is causing this shift in coordinates?

Tags: gps

I'm working on taking raw GPS measurements and getting a position from them. It involves double differencing measurements from a fixed base station (with a known position) and a rover (in my case, an airplane). I'm following the procedure explained by Geoffrey Blewitt in [Basics of the GPS Technique: Observation Equations](http://www.nbmg.unr.edu/staff/pdfs/blewitt%20basics%20of%20gps.pdf), starting on page 36.

My problem is, the position I get from this solution is very consistently off by 15 meters or so, with X, Y, and Z coordinates all off by a set amount (5, 10, and 9 meters, respectively). This happens even if the plane is turning.

I've tried accounting for the ionosphere by using an [ionosphere-free combination](https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/Ionosphere-free_Combination_for_Dual_Frequency_Receivers) of L1 and L2 measurements. The troposphere shouldn't be an issue due to the short baseline in my case (~5km). And since the measurements are double differenced, I shouldn't have to account for satellite or receiver clock delays.

This leads me to my question: What other sources of error exist in GPS that could cause a translational shift like the one I'm experiencing? Did I miss something? And if so, how do I correct it?

Comment: How do you know you're off?

Comment: I have processed positions from professional software (Novatel Waypoint).

Comment: Check all the settings in the Novatel Waypoint software. You're looking for anything that might modify the coordinates...like combined scale factor/grid-to-ground/reduction to surface/etc.

Comment: The logs I'm working with are directly from the Novatel GPS, I'm just using Waypoint to plot it. It doesn't look like any scaling or coordinate modification is being done.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the distance that NADCON shifts between NAD27 and WGS84 points in your study area?  https://gisgeography.com/geodetic-datums-nad27-nad83-wgs84/

Comment: About 53 meters. The output coordinates are in WGS84, so that's what I've been working in.